# How do i specify the dimension of image output in python subprocess?

Tags: python, imagemagick, subprocess, imagemagick-convert

I want to convert pdf file to image. I want to specify the output dimension for images. How do I do that?

```
import subprocess
#I want to pass output dimension as parameter. How do I do that 
params = ['convert','./data/in.pdf','thumnails.jpg']
subprocess.check_call(params)
```

Comment: `convert` is image-magick command line program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't really use `image-magick` nor its `convert` command-line command. But I done some researching and found out you can use the `-resize` parameter to resize images. You can refer back to [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19676#p77537) and [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize) and also [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=21324#p86984) for more details. To incorporate it to running from `subprocess`, you can do:

```
import subprocess
#I want to pass output dimension as parameter. How do I do that 
params = ['convert','./data/in.pdf','-resize', '100x100', 'thumnails.jpg'] # replace 100x100 with your width x height 
subprocess.check_call(params)
```

Alternatively, you can try using the `-density` argument:

```
params = ['convert', '-density', '100x100', './data/in.pdf', 'thumnails.jpg'] # replace 100x100 with your width x height
```

Comment: `-resize` didn't work but `-density` parameter worked. Maybe because input was a pdf file.

Comment: haha, like I said, I don't use that tool... but I can find links:), anyways, glad you found your solution though.